# Why jQuery .load() is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `itscript.js`:

```
$(".zoradenie a").click(function()
  {   
    showLoader();
    pageurl = '/' + $(this).attr("kategoria") + '/' + $(this).attr("podkategoria") + '.html?vyrobca=' + $(this).attr("vyrobca") + '&zoradenie=' + $(this).attr("sort");

    history.pushState('data', '', pageurl);
    $(".produkty").load("/produkty.php?Kategoria=" + $(this).attr("kategoria") + "&Podkategoria=" + $(this).attr("podkategoria") + "page=1", hideLoader);
  });
```

And in `index.php` I have:

```
        <script src="itscript.js"></script>
```

And it is not working. Why would this be?

jQuery's .load() does nothing.

Comment: Does it even *call* `.load()`?  Does your `<script>` tag appear in the `<head>`?

Comment: Have you wrapped this in a `document.ready`?

Comment: Checked your console for errors?

Comment: Yes. I test add the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`. Yes, the itscript.js beginning with document.ready.

Comment: I have in the script some PHP code. Some like: `$(".produkty").load("/produkty.php?<?php if($_GET['vyhladavanie']){ echo 'vyhladavanie';  } else { echo 'Kategoria'; }  ?>=<?php  if($_GET['Kategoria']){     echo $_GET['Kategoria'];  } else {`

Answer (score 3):

Added `&`  for `+ "&page=1"`

```
  $(".produkty").load("produkty.php?Kategoria=" + $(this).attr("kategoria") + "&Podkategoria=" + $(this).attr("podkategoria") + "&page=1", hideLoader);
```

instead of

```
 $(".produkty").load("/produkty.php?Kategoria=" + $(this).attr("kategoria") + "&Podkategoria=" + $(this).attr("podkategoria") + "page=1", hideLoader);
```